# thymeleaf Field Attr Processor doesnt work

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I encountered the following error with following architecture. what is the error?

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for
> /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. There was an unexpected
> error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Error during execution
> of processor
> 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputRadioFieldAttrProcessor'
> (hotel:24)

​

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Knight list</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />

    <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form th:object="${hotel1}" th:action="@{/kniths}" th:method="${post}" >
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Hotel</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <ul><label  >Hotels</label>
        <li th:each="hotel : ${hotels}">
            <input type="radio" th:field="*{hotels}" th:value="${hotel.id}" />
            <label  th:text="${hotel.name}"></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </tbody>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

​

```
@Controller
public class HotelControler {

    @Autowired
    HotelService hotelService;

    @RequestMapping("/newhotel")
    public String addHotel(Model model){
        Hotel hotel1 = new Hotel();
        List<Hotel> hotels = hotelService.getAllHotels();
        model.addAttribute("hotel", hotel1);
        model.addAttribute("hotels",hotels);
        System.out.println(hotel1.getName());
        return "hotel";
    }
}
```

​

```
public class Hotel {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=20, message="min 2 znaki maximum 20 znakow")
    private String name;
    private int cena;
    private int id;

    public Hotel (){}

    public Hotel(int id, String name, int cena){
        this.id=id;this.name=name;this.cena=222;
    }

    public Hotel(String name, int cena){
        this.cena=cena;
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(int id, String name){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }

    public void setCena(int cena){
        this.cena=cena;
    }

    public int getCena(){
        return this.cena;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Hotel " + name + "oferuje wpokoje w cenie " + cena;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stacktrace please.

Answer (score 0):

Controller hotel model attribute value is incorrect and its must be change like this.

```
model.addAttribute("hotel1", hotel1);
```

In view `th:field` need to be change to "name" attribute of hotel.

```
 <input type="radio" th:field="*{name}" th:value="${hotel.id}" />
```